# Hide JetBrains annotation on popup JavaDoc in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to hide or **turn off** those **Inferred Annotations Available** when I'm reading the popup documentation from a method.

As outlined on the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting in IntelliJ IDEA to disable it.

I've [submitted a request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179266), please vote.

Comment: Do they have any plan or ticket to create that feature ?

Comment: It's not clear where this setting can be added, we don't like adding a lot of options since IDE already has too many. One workaround could be making it a Registry option/VM option key. There is no existing request yet, you can file one at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA or I can do it for you.

Comment: It pollutes a lot the Javadoc pop up...Create an issue for me, please !