# Suppress "Inferred annotations available" in quick documentation in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

The Quick Documentation popup for methods sometimes shows "Inferred annotations available" or "External annotations available", mostly regarding whether a parameter or a return value can be null.

I would rather not see these and only see the actual documentation for the method. Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done right now, but a fix for this issue is scheduled for later this month in release 2017.3.3. (The current release is 2017.3.2.)

See [IDEA-179266 Option to hide inferred annotations in Quick Documentation popup](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179266)

~~~~~~~

Update:

I just noticed that the bugfix arose from another SO post on this issue. See [Hide JetBrains annotation on popup JavaDoc in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178075/hide-jetbrains-annotation-on-popup-javadoc-in-intellij)